# Creating Grid Graphics Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

I'm doing a project where I create a counter clockwise spiral of natural numbers with rectangles. An example of this is shown below:

Spiral natural numbers:
[image: spiral natural numbers]

Instead of colors with numbers in them, using Tkinter grid() or canvas, I want to be able to create, until some value, these spiraling rectangles. In the image, the stopping value was 13, having 13 rectangles.

I have the framework for the grid:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GridCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw_rectangle)
        self.grid_size = 20  # Adjust the grid size as needed
        self.draw_grid()

    def draw_grid(self):
        for i in range(0, self.winfo_reqwidth(), self.grid_size):
            self.create_line(i, 0, i, self.winfo_reqheight(), fill="gray", dash=(2, 2))
        for i in range(0, self.winfo_reqheight(), self.grid_size):
            self.create_line(0, i, self.winfo_reqwidth(), i, fill="gray", dash=(2, 2))

    def draw_rectangle(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        x1 = (x // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        y1 = (y // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        x2 = x1 + self.grid_size
        y2 = y1 + self.grid_size
        self.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill="blue", stipple="gray50")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Grid Canvas")

    canvas = GridCanvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="white")
    canvas.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

    root.mainloop()
```

but I can't figure out a way to create the rectangles. If anyone has any questions, I would be happy to clarify. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? You have function `draw_rectangle` and you have to run it. Do you get error message when you run in console/terminal? Then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Comment: in every move you cycle list `(move up, move left, move bottom, move right)` and moves creates list with pairs (+1, +1, +2, +2, +3, +3, +4, +4, ...) so every 2 moves you have to increase it, or you can count moves and increate on odd or even move. Eventually you can create generator for this. `v = 1 ; while True: yield v ; yield v; v += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need generator to cycle direction `up`,`left`,`down`,`right`

```
def cycle_direction():

    # (dx, dy)
    values = (
        ( 0,-1),  # up
        (-1, 0),  # left
        ( 0, 1),  # down
        ( 1, 0),  # right
    )

    while True:
        for x in values:
            yield x
```

(of course you could use `itertools.cycle()` for this)

And generator to calculate length before next change of direction.
It seems it increases length after two changes of direction `(+1, +1, +2, +2, +3, +3, ....)`

```
def length():
    size = 1
    while True:
        yield size
        yield size
        size += 1
```

Now it needs nested loops. First to get direction and size, second to draw rectangles.

I convert `draw_rectangle()` to normal function which gets `x, y, color` so I use it in code.

```
    def run_example(self):
        # start position
        x = 200
        y = 200
        
        # draw first rectangle
        self.draw_rectangle(x, y)
        root.update()     # force tkinter to redraw window
        time.sleep(0.5)   # slow down to see how it change
    
        # generators
        gen_direction = cycle_direction()
        gen_length    = length()
        gen_color     = cycle_color()
                
        for _ in range(10):
            dx, dy = next(gen_direction)
            l = next(gen_length)
            #c = next(gen_color)
            
            for _ in range(l):
            
                x += (dx * self.grid_size)
                y += (dy * self.grid_size)

                print( (dx, dy) , x, y)
                
                self.draw_rectangle(x, y) #, color=c)
                root.update()    # force tkinter to redraw window
                time.sleep(0.5)  # slow down to see how it change
                
    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        self.draw_rectangle(event.x, event.y)
        
    def draw_rectangle(self, x, y, color="blue"):
        x1 = (x // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        y1 = (y // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        x2 = x1 + self.grid_size
        y2 = y1 + self.grid_size
        self.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, stipple="gray50")
```

It still need to count cells to change color in correct moment.

---

Full working code (after image):

[image]

I use `self.after` to start example after showing canvas.

I use `time.sleep()` only to show how it changes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def length():
    size = 1
    while True:
        yield size
        yield size
        size += 1
        
def cycle_direction():

    # (dx, dy)
    values = (
        ( 0,-1),  # up
        (-1, 0),  # left
        ( 0, 1),  # down
        ( 1, 0),  # right
    )

    while True:
        for x in values:
            yield x

def cycle_color():

    values = ("blue", 'red', 'green', 'yellow')

    while True:
        for x in values:
            yield x
        
class GridCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_mouse_motion)
        self.grid_size = 20  # Adjust the grid size as needed
        self.draw_grid()
    
        # run after showing canvas
        self.after(1000, self.run_example)

    def run_example(self):
        # start position
        x = 200
        y = 200
        
        # draw first rectangle
        self.draw_rectangle(x, y)
        root.update()     # force tkinter to redraw window
        time.sleep(0.5)   # slow down to see how it change
    
        # generators
        gen_direction = cycle_direction()
        gen_length    = length()
        gen_color     = cycle_color()
                
        for _ in range(10):
            dx, dy = next(gen_direction)
            l = next(gen_length)
            #c = next(gen_color)
            
            for _ in range(l):
            
                x += (dx * self.grid_size)
                y += (dy * self.grid_size)

                print( (dx, dy) , x, y)
                
                self.draw_rectangle(x, y) #, color=c)
                root.update()  # force tkinter to redraw window
                time.sleep(0.5)   # slow down to see how it change
                
    def draw_grid(self):
        for i in range(0, self.winfo_reqwidth(), self.grid_size):
            self.create_line(i, 0, i, self.winfo_reqheight(), fill="gray", dash=(2, 2))
        for i in range(0, self.winfo_reqheight(), self.grid_size):
            self.create_line(0, i, self.winfo_reqwidth(), i, fill="gray", dash=(2, 2))

    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        self.draw_rectangle(event.x, event.y)
        
    def draw_rectangle(self, x, y, color="blue"):
        x1 = (x // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        y1 = (y // self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        x2 = x1 + self.grid_size
        y2 = y1 + self.grid_size
        self.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, stipple="gray50")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Grid Canvas")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with colors:

```
    def run_example(self):
        # start position
        x = 200
        y = 200
        next_count = 1
        count = next_count
        
        # draw first rectangle
        self.draw_rectangle(x, y)
        root.update()     # force tkinter to redraw window
        time.sleep(0.5)   # slow down to see how it change
    
        # generators
        gen_direction = cycle_direction()
        gen_length    = length()
        gen_color     = cycle_color()
        c = next(gen_color)
                
        for _ in range(10):
            dx, dy = next(gen_direction)
            l = next(gen_length)
            
            for _ in range(l):
            
                count -= 1
                if count == 0:
                    next_count += 1
                    count = next_count
                    c = next(gen_color)
                
                x += (dx * self.grid_size)
                y += (dy * self.grid_size)

                print( (dx, dy) , x, y)
                
                self.draw_rectangle(x, y, color=c)
                root.update()  # force tkinter to redraw window
                time.sleep(0.5)   # slow down to see how it change
```

[image]